# Building a regex: replacing a number of '?' with an integer equal to the number of '?'s?

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm, replace

I'm trying to build a regex String given another String. For example, given:

```
*FILE???.LOG
```

What I want is to replace the character '*' with **\w+** and the characters **???** with **\w{number of ?}**, i.e.:

```
\w+FILE\w{3}.LOG
```

I know that a simple *replace()* can take care of the '*'. What I'm really having trouble with is to replace the **?**.
What I tried to do was to split the string in such a manner that I would be able to know the start and end index of the sequence of **?**. (One of the regex I tried to use, for example, was **[^\x3F]** but, in some cases, I get the wrong answer.)

Currently I'm replacing it by brute force, checking each character to see whether it is a question mark or not. When it is not, I just append the character to a new String. When it is, I start to count the length of the sequence of question marks until the sequence ends. When it does, I append **\w{number of ?}** to the new String, and so on. At the end of the algorithm, my output is a new String formatted the way I want.

I believe this algorithm is *O(n)* but I wonder if there is any way of doing this replacement using regex, which would be cheaper and simpler to implement, or if there's another more efficient way to do this.

Other examples:

```
        INPUT       ||          OUTPUT 
------------------------------------------------------
??FILE.L???         ||     \w{2}FILE.L\w{3}
??plugin??.L*       ||     \w{2}plugin\w{2}.L\w+
plugin.L??          ||     plugin.L\w{2}
monitor???.???      ||     monitor\w{3}.\w{3}
pl???ugin??*.L???   ||     plu\w{3}ugin\w{2}\w+.L\w{3}
*???.L?             ||     \w+\w{3}.L\w{1}
```

PS.: I'm using **Java**.

Comment: The regex will be more costly/less efficient than a for..loop, and it will be just as, if not more, difficult to maintain a regex match while..loop. Just check out @stribizhev's answer, is it more or less complex than your for loop questionmark counter?

Comment: Indeed, @LouisRicci... I'll check it out. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve both replacements with one regex:

```
String fileText = "pl???ugin??*.L???";
String pattern = "(?<q>\\?+)|(?<a>\\*+)";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(fileText);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group("q") != null)
    {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "\\\\w{" + m.group("q").length() + "}");
    }
    else if (m.group("a") != null) 
    {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "\\\\w+");
    }
}
m.appendTail(sb); // append the rest of the contents
System.out.println(sb);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/gf82BY)

For `pl???ugin??*.L???`, result is `pl\w{3}ugin\w{2}\w+.L\w{3}`.

In short, the `(?<q>\\?+)|(?<a>\\*+)` regex captures question marks into group "q", and asterisks into group "a". Inside the `find()`, we check which group we have captured, and based on that information, we build the result.

**Note** that I assume any number of asterisks should be replaced with `\w+`. If you need to replace *each* asterisk with `\w+`, use the `(?<q>\\?+)|(?<a>\\*)` regex.

Comment: Thank you, @stribizhev ! That is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Not at all, upvoting and accepting an answer is already a million thanks to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace each `?` with `\w`.

Ex:

```
\w+FILE\w\w\w.LOG
```

Comment: This is a pretty reasonable answer. The resulting regex string may be larger but the compiled regex would run the same whether you use *\w\w\w* or *\w{3}*. The simplicity to implement -- return s.replace("*", "\\w+").replace("?", "\\w") -- wins hands down.